# How to use existing stored procedure & functions with Entity Framework Code-first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

I'm using `EntityFramework.Functions` library that is used to call a stored procedure or a function when we use Entity Framework code-first.

I have a stored procedure that returns a nullable long value. But I get an error:

> System.Nullable`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] for method AddRecord_SP is not supported in conceptual model as a structural type.

The functions is declared in my `DataContext` class:

```
[Function(FunctionType.StoredProcedure, "Sp_name", Schema = "acnt")]
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<long>> AddRecord_SP(string i_Params)
{
     var i_ParamsParameter = i_Params != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("I_Params", i_Params) :
            new ObjectParameter("I_Params", typeof(string));

     return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<long>>("Sp_name", i_ParamsParameter);
}
```

Comment: Please add code that calls `AddRecord_SP` for more detail.

Comment: I don't have any code calls this method. I have only a definition of my SP structure in datacontext class

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Stored procedures can't actually specify that parameters are non-nullable.

May be you can try to specify the  return parameters.

```
 [return: Parameter(DbType = "")]
```

Below is Sample Code from My project you can refer.

```
[Function(FunctionType.StoredProcedure, "GetTop100", Schema = "biz")]
    public IQueryable<GetTop100Emp> GetTop100EmpList(long? FKTenant,  int IsFilter)
    {
        var parameters = new ObjectParameter[] {
            new ObjectParameter("FKTenant", FKTenant),
            new ObjectParameter("IsFilter", IsFilter),
        };
        return this.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetTop100Emp>("GetTop100", parameters).AsQueryable<GetTop100Emp>();
```